# Combine results from two queries?

Tags: mysql, subquery, union, drupal

I need to combine the results from two queries into one result set and order them altogether.

This is the working, raw SQL code I have:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
      t1.id AS entity_id,
      t2.title,
      'query1' AS entity_type
    FROM
      `table1` t1,
      `table2` t2
    WHERE
      t1.id = t2.id
  UNION ALL
    SELECT
      t3.id AS entity_id,
      t4.title,
      'query2' AS entity_type
    FROM
      `table3` t3,
      `table4` t4
    WHERE
      t3.id = t4.id
) AS results ORDER BY results.entity_id
```

The query above works perfectly, but I need to convert it into a specific syntax for a CMS database API, which does not support such queries.

I am looking for something without the `SELECT * FROM(subquery)` as such queries can be converted easily.

Is there any command I can use to `UNION ALL` and order records from both sub-queries?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider taking the union queries and make a view using them.  You can then treat the union as if it was a table.

Comment: Almost perfectly. The potential pitfall here is that this often scales poorly since `UNION` causes views to be rendered with the [`TEMPTABLE` algorithm](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/view-algorithms.html) which means the result of the `SELECT` inside the view is fetched into an implicit temporary table, and then any `WHERE` clause applied to the outer `SELECT` from the view is applied to the temporary table, removing the ability to use indexes to satisfy the `WHERE` clause used against the view (only `WHERE` clauses that are part of the view definition itself can still use indexes).

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thanks for the heads up. Is there anything I can do to avoid this? Is there any other alternative?

Comment: @Ivanhoe123 potentially, but it will depend on the nature of the restrictions in your CMS interface; if the view, itself, returns a small result and you don't need an outer `WHERE` then the view is no worse than the original query, which most likely will create a temp table anyway, since table indexes can't be used for sorting the result of `UNION`.

Comment: Thanks again for the explanation. Will keep that in mind and test these options.